# Scala: Count Words

Tags: scala, dictionary, functional-programming

I am trying to write the function of countWords(ws) that counts the frequency of words in a list of words ws returning a map from words to occurrences.
that ws is a List[String], using the List data type I should produce a Map[String,Int] using the Map data type. an example of what should the function do:

```
def test{
    expect (Map("aa" -> 2, "bb" -> 1)) { 
      countWords(List("aa", "bb"))
    }
  }
```

This is just a perpetration for a test and its not an assignment. I have been stuck on this function for while now. This is what I have so far:

```
object Solution { 
 // define function countWords 
 def countWords(ws : List[String]) : Map[String,Int] = ws match {
   case List() => List()
 }
}//
```

which gives type mismatch. I am not quite sure how to use the scala Map Function, for example when ws is Empty list what should it return that passed by `Map[String,Int]` I have been trying, and thats why I post it here to get some help. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is this

```
def countWords(ws: List[String]): Map[String, Int] = {
  ws.toSet.map((word: String) => (word, ws.count(_ == word))).toMap
}
```

But it's not the fastest one since it searches through the list several times.

edit:

The fastest way is to use a mutable HashMap

```
def countWords(ws: List[String]): Map[String, Int] = {
  val map = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.empty[String, Int]
  for(word <- ws) {
    val n = map.getOrElse(word, 0)
    map += (word -> (n + 1))
  }
  map.toMap
}
```

Comment: wow, great thanks, any tips for me about how to do these kind of stuff? I am fairly new to scala.

Comment: Look at the api documentation http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current and read through tutorials on scala and scala collections.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it is using `groupBy` which outputs `Map(baz -> List(baz, baz, baz), foo -> List(foo, foo), bar -> List(bar))`. Then you can map the values of the `Map` with `mapValues` to get a count of the number of times each word appears.

```
scala> List("foo", "foo", "bar", "baz", "baz", "baz")
res0: List[String] = List(foo, foo, bar, baz, baz, baz)

scala> res0.groupBy(x => x).mapValues(_.size)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(baz -> 3, foo -> 2, bar -> 1)
```

Regarding the type mismatch in your program `countWords` is expecting a `Map[String, Int]` as the return type and the first(and only) match you have returns an empty `List` with type `Nothing`. If you change the match to `case List() => Map[String, Int]()` it will no longer give a type error. It also gives a warning about an in-exhaustive pattern match obviously won't return the correct output.

Comment: @david `size` returns the number of items in a collection. e.g. `List("a", "b","c").size` retrurns `3`.

Answer (score 2):

Use fold to go through your list starting with an empty map

```
ws.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int]){
(count, word) => count + (word -> (count.getOrElse(word, 0) + 1))
}
```

Comment: wow, great thanks, any tips for me about how to do these kind of stuff? I am fairly new to scala.

Comment: I did the scala  course on coursera, highly recommend it
It mixes the perfect amount of theory with practical coding, blew my mind